# The code below reads from a text argument and displays an m x n matrice, I want to pass another text argument and compare it with the first 1

Tags: java, stdout, stdin

```
// here is a sample text file below board.txt
/* 4 4
   x t x .
   . . s .
   x . . .

moves.txt lru
l for left, r for right u for up and d for down.

The first text file argument is a board game file on which s represents a start position and t the target.
and the second text file argument is a moves text file. I want to pass the second argument so that I can make those moves across the board file.
*/ 
public class VGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                int m = StdIn.readInt(); 
                int n = StdIn.readInt(); 

                String[][] board1 = new String[m][n];                 
                for (int i = 0; i < board1.length; i++) { 
// the condition becomes false then gives access back to the outer for loop
                    for (int j = 0; j < board1[i].length; j++) { 
                       board1[i][j] = StdIn.readString();                 //reading from a text files
                    }
                } 
                                                                // now let's print a two dimensional array in Java for 

                /*for (char[] a : board1)
                 { 
                    for (char i : a)
                 { 

                 System.out.print(i + " "); 

                } System.out.println("\n");

                } */

                StdOut.println(m + " " + n);

                for (int i = 0; i < board1.length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < board1[i].length; j++) 
                    {
                        System.out.print(" "+ board1[i][j]);
                    }

                    System.out.println();
                }

                // printing 2D array using Arrays.deepToString() method 
                   //System.out.println("another way to print 2D arrays");

                 //System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board1));

                StdOut.println(args[0]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's with all the blank lines? Makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

this should read the indexes as Integer and then the String line-by-line.

```
 public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int m = 0;
        int n = 0;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("input m: ");
        m = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("input n: ");
        n = s.nextInt();


        String[][] board1 = new String[m][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)

        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

            {
                System.out.print("input string: ");
                board1[i][j] = s.nextLine();

            }

        }

        s.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)

        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)

            {
                System.out.println(board1[i][j]);

            }

        }

    }

}
```